# action.CALL_DIAL set +1 on phone number

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Actualy with the new update, Im getting some troubles with this source code, cos' add a +1 on the phone number. Anyone get the same problem?

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent();
localIntent.putExtra("com.google.glass.extra.PHONE_NUMBER", callTo);
localIntent.setAction("com.google.glass.action.CALL_DIAL");
sendBroadcast(localIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that happened to me too. I had to explicitly add the country code and that fixed the issue.

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent();
localIntent.putExtra("com.google.glass.extra.PHONE_NUMBER", "+61282294333");
localIntent.setAction("com.google.glass.action.CALL_DIAL");
```

Not sure it works on all countries but I've tried a couple countries and it worked fine.

Comment: Men your solution it's quite good! I don't know if I can manage this on all the phones, but it's a solution. Thanks!